# Is there any Firefox addon that helps me to use only Keyboard?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, browser-addons

I know Vimperator. However, I would only like to have a feature similar as in Opera and Vimperator that allows me to browse links either by numbers or by TAB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox Mouseless browsing addon should be what you're looking for: http://www.rudolf-noe.de/index.php?/content/view/14/26/

Answer (score 2):

Firefox already has many keyboard shortcuts.

Here is a list,

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard+shortcuts

Comment: These are only keyboard shortcuts for menu commands, go to next tabbed windows, etc. There are no shortcuts for navigating spatially on a page. The closest is the TAB key, but is impractical as it moves horizonally unless a link is the last in a line. BTW: thanks for letting me discover that F6 changes focus to the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox already allows you to browse links by TAB.  Each TAB will take you to the next link on the page.

Comment: But this is impractical as it moves horizonally unless a link is the last in a line. It takes far too many TABS to get to the desired link.

Answer (score 1):

The Vimperator add-on also provides Vim-like bindings to Firefox, if you're a Vim user.